# How to fill matrix using Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to learn some functional programing and streams in Java, here is the matrix that I want to receive:

```
Integer[][] availableValues = new Integer[][]{{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
```

Is there any way to fill this matrix with given values but using Streams? (pseudo code)

```
for array in matrix
  for value in array
    for range(1,4)
      value = next value between 1 and 4
```

Is there any way to put values from 1 to X in every array in matrix using Streams?
Something like `Arrays.stream(availableValues).map(x->IntStream.range(1,10).forEach(i -> x = i));` but it's obviously not working.

Comment: The pseudo cote is confusing. Why would you have three nested loops to initialize a two dimensional array? To overwrite the values of an existing array, you can use `Arrays.stream(availableValues).forEach(a -> Arrays.setAll(a, i -> i + 1));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- You want to create 4 arrays of arrays of size 3 that each contain 1,2,3.
- the mapped inner stream creates one of those arrays.
- the outer stream does that 4 times and creates an array of those arrays.

```
int[][] v = IntStream.range(1, 5)
        .mapToObj(a -> IntStream.range(1, 4).toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

for (int[] arr : v) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Nice solution. Nice and fast :)

Comment: I’d use other ranges, `range(0, 4)` for the outer stream, to document that it will create `4` arrays and `rangeClosed(1, 3)` for the inner, to document that it willl produce the values from `1` to `3`…

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```java
int[][] arr = IntStream.range(0, 4)
                       .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(1, 4).toArray())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(int[][]::new);
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: There is no need to collect into a `List` before calling `toArray`, as you can call `toArray` on the stream directly.